# How to use variables in CMS-System in Magento 1.8

Tags: magento-1.8

I try to make my first steps in magento. I would like to make a CMS-Page and 
is there a possibility to use variables in CMS-System in Magento 1.8 ?

For example i create a page and in this page i would like to say Hello `{{ user }}` when the user is logged in.

Comment: Besides it's quite a broad topic and I would advise you to follow some tutorials first, the [Magento Stack Exchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/) would be a more suitable source for you.

Comment: Can you recommend good tutorials for magento ?

Comment: @GregOstry you can do by calling phtml file in cms block and code in phtml file

Comment: Nah, but [google can](https://www.google.com/search?q=magento+tutorials)